# AndEngine Box2D forces to move a falling character

Tags: box2d, physics, andengine

I'm developing a side-scroller game like Super Mario. I'm trying to move a character using `setLinearVelocity()`, but this doesn't seem to work properly. When the character falls and then starts moving, he doesn't continue to fall but only moves.

This is a code snippet:

```
Sprite backward = new Sprite( -50, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 170, backwardr){
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pEvent, float pX, float pY){
        if(!pEvent.isActionUp()){
            charactersprite.getTextureRegion().setFlippedHorizontal(true);
            body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(3,0)); // There's the problem

        }else{
            body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0,0)); // Don't look at there
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: ...I see no question whatsoever. What are you asking? You might want to clarify.

Comment: I'm asking how to move character? ( I tried to move with setLinearVelocity(...); but it don't work properly, becouse when the character falls and starts moving, then he don't fall, but only move.

Comment: I have updated your question for you. Please check if it's properly stated. This is the kind of information you should normally clearly indicate.

Comment: I editted it. Thanks! Please help!

Comment: I doesn't work. That function does not exist. Please help me!

Comment: Worked! Thanks! Sorry for my stupid things! ... :D

Comment: If you solved the problem, post an answer containing the information that you used and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with :

```
Sprite backward = new Sprite( -50, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 170, backwardr){
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pEvent, float pX, float pY){
    if(!pEvent.isActionUp()){
        charactersprite.getTextureRegion().setFlippedHorizontal(true);
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(3,body.getLinearVelocity.y)); // There's the problem

    }else{
        body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0,getLinearVelocity.y)); // Don't look at there
    }
    return false;
}
};
```